# Converting a string into a table format with columns

Tags: python

```
The file name is studs.txt and this is what is inside:
12345 2 G400 Bart Simpson
12346 1 GH46 Lisa Simpson
12347 2 G401 Homer J Simpson
12348 4 H610 Hermione Grainger
12349 3 G400 Harry Potter
12350 1 G402 Herschel Shmoikel Krustofski
13123 3 G612 Wayne Rooney

x = input("Enter a filename: ")
try:
    o = open(x, "r")
    p = o.read()
    y = tuple(j for j in p.splitlines())
    m = " ".join(map(str, y))
    print(m) 
    o.close()
except IOError as e :
    print("File Does Not Exist")
```

When I run this code it will import this file "studs.txt" and put it into a string however I want to convert that string into a table format and in a specific layout in order for it to look like this:

```
Simpson, Bart    12345    G400   2
Simpson, Lisa    12346    G401   1
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do as follows:

```
try:
    o = open(x, "r")
    p = o.read()
    y = tuple(j.split() for j in p.splitlines())
    #m = " ".join(map(str, y))
    for v1,v2,v3,fname,*rest_of_name in y:
        #print(v1,v2,v3,fname,*rest_of_name)

        if int(v1) != some_year:  
            continue;

        print("{:<30} {:<10} {:<5} {:<5}".format(fname + ', ' +  ' '.join(rest_of_name), v1,v3, v2))
    o.close()
except IOError as e :
    print("File Does Not Exist")
```

This prints:

```
Bart, Simpson                  12345      G400  2    
Lisa, Simpson                  12346      GH46  1    
Homer, J Simpson               12347      G401  2    
Hermione, Grainger             12348      H610  4    
Harry, Potter                  12349      G400  3    
Herschel, Shmoikel Krustofski  12350      G402  1    
Wayne, Rooney                  13123      G612  3
```

Comment: thanks for the help I really appreciate it, would you know how to do for example if I asked the user if they want to see only the people from year then it'll print only bart simpson and homer simpson along with the other two columns ?

Comment: Yep, just add if condition in the for loop to check the year. Not sure which variable is year.

Comment: I added the condition to the loop. You need to prompt a user before that for the year and convert the year string to int.

Comment: i'm still having trouble trying to print out the users information who are in year 2 for some reason

Comment: Maybe make new questions, with example of what you trying to do, and what error you have.

Comment: I didnt know they have any question limits. Maybe try in few minutes. Maybe than you can make new question.